# Outlook Add In : Is it possible to discard changes to a mailItem programatically ?

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I have created an outlook add in which modifies the attachment and the body of the message when the user opens the mail. However, whenever I close the window , there is a prompt which asks me if I want to save the changes made to both the attachments and the properties of the message.

What I would like to ask is that , is there any way for me to discard the changes programatically so that the mail will return to the state before I opened it ?

I have also used Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_mailItem); , but the prompt still appears .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call `mailItem.Close(OlInspectorClose.olDiscard);`.

Comment: I have tried using this in the mailItem close event but what happens is that the prompt:  "The attachments for this message have been changed. Do you want to save?" does not appear , and my mail message gets saved automatically .  

are there any other alternatives ? I just want it to return to it's original state upon closing of the mail window. 

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can call Close from the Close event handler. You can set the Cancel parameter to true in the Close event handler, start up a timer, then in the timer event handler call MailItem.Close(olDiscard)- by that time you will be out of the Close event handler.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, 
Thanks for the advice! It opened up whole new possibilities for me to do what I wanted to do. It works =D .

Comment: Juts make sure you are using the Timer from the Forms namespace (it runs on the main thread) instead of the Timer from the System namespace (it uses a secondary thread).